# Is there a closed form expression for the intersection point of a linear function and a exponential function?

Tags: functions, roots

$$ a x = be^{cx} - 1 $$
where $a,b,c$ are constant and $a > 0, 0 < b < 1$ and $c>0$. Is there a closed form expression for this function?

Comment: There's an expression in terms of the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by "closed-form expression" you mean a function that takes as parameters the constants $a,b,c$ determining the linear function and the exponential and returns the $x$-value of the intersection point.

> Solve[a x == b E^(c x) - 1, x]

in Mathematica yields (as pointed out in the comments)

$$ x = \dfrac{-c - a \cdot W \left( - \frac{b c\operatorname{e}^{- \frac{c}{a}}}{a}\right)}{a c},$$ where $W$ is the [Lambert W-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).
I hope this helps.

Comment: Good, that is what I want.  Thanks!